# OOP: should there be category class and how to handle measuring units?

Tags: php, oop

This is my first bigger project so I want to do things right.
I am planning to make product class which I later want to group or filter.

Example of object

```
product {
  name: 'chicken breast';
  amount: 100g;
  energyVal: {
   protein : 10g;
   carbs: 20g;
   fat: 10g;
}
```

**Problem 1:**

Later on I want them to be grouped if the food is vegan, vegetarian, meat or etc.

**Question:**

Should the product category be an attribute as energyVal in the product object or should another class like productCategory/productList/veganProduct be created and how should it then look like. The reason I am not sure is because I think that foreaching trough all objects and checking if the attribute is equals vegan would take long time and does not seem like a very good practice. Correct me if I'm wrong

**Problem 2:**

The project should be available worldwide it means that different measuring units and languages should be considered.

**Question:**
For the language is probably not necessary to have that own class, but what about measuring units ?

Eventually references and links or examples on planning bigger OOP projects are also welcome which could answer my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem 2" is the simplest: you store all the measurements in SI units (metric) and convert them, when you are producing a response, based on users localization options.

As for "problem 1" ... well ... I would assume, that each product would belong in multiple categories (many-to-many on the SQL side). I would use a separate class for that. The APU would be kinda like this:

```
$categories = new CategoryCollection;
$mapper = new CategoryMapper;

$categories->forProduct($productID);
$mapper->fetch($categories);

// .. etc.
```

You have to also consider, that, when you search for "vegetarian" products, the users would also expect the "vegan" ones to show up (as in - your categories might require a tree-based "inheritance").